# jQuery Form library not work in partial view

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4, jqueryform

The following code work fine in regular View but not in partial view

```
<script>
$.noConflict();
var uniqueId = '@Guid.NewGuid().ToString()';
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {


    console.log(uniqueId);
    $("#Myform input[name='clientId']").val(uniqueId);
    console.log($("#Myform input[name='clientId']").val());

    var bar = $('.progress-bar');
    var percent = $('.percent');
    var status = $('#status');

    $('#Myform').ajaxForm({
        beforeSend: function () {
            status.empty();
            var percentVal = '0%';
            bar.width(percentVal);
            percent.html(percentVal);
            $("#pleaseWaitDialog").modal({ backdrop: 'static', keyboard: false });
            $('#statusBorder').show();

            //$("#pleaseWaitDialog").modal({ backdrop: 'static', keyboard: false });
        },
        uploadProgress: function (event, position, total, percentComplete) {

            var percentVal = percentComplete + '%';
            bar.width(percentVal);
            percent.html(percentVal);
        },
        complete: function (xhr) {
            getStatus();
            status.html(xhr.responseText);
            //$("#pleaseWaitDialog").modal('hide');
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

I've got a error **"$(...).ajaxform is not a function"**

Here what i already tried:

1. manipulating with position of javascript libraries calls
2. double check that there is no conflicts of javascript/jquery library calls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Partial view isn't loaded when the page loads.

You must force that the function called after the partial view loaded.

You are doing it:

1. by event trigger (that happens by user in the partial view)
2. by event trigger of the page.
3. jast in  tag

the most elegant ways is the first two option.